# how to make byobu start with terminator by default?

Tags: byobu, terminator

Recently, I have been using byobu and I quite like it. However, I am more of a terminator user than gnome-terminal and I want to launch byobu inside terminator instead of gnome-terminal by default.
How do i do that?

edit: what i want is click the byobu icon and open byobu inside terminator instead of gnome terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into Terminator's Preferences > Profile > Command > Run a custom command instead of my shell and add it.

You need to <kbd>F9</kbd> once it opens and set it as well.

Comment: nice one! this is the other way but nice!

Comment: I've tried to follow your instructions but when I create another window with Terminator(Ctrl+Shift+E or Ctrl+Shift+O).. everything that I wrote show in all windows of Terminator+Byobu. ps. The Broadcasting Group feature of Terminator is off.

Answer (score 2):

Byobu reattaches the screen session. Try the command

`terminator -x byobu bash`

to start a new session.